# Google Cloud SQL configuration - get OAuth 2 token via GoogleCL for SQL or Eclipse

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, eclipse-plugin, google-cloud-sql

Configuring Google Cloud SQL to work with an app built using GWT Eclipse EE Plugin and am having authentication issues.

#### Google Command Line Tool - try running ./google_sql.sh *instance*

Need guidance setting up GoogleCL for CloudSQL. I installed regular GoogleCL using MacPorts.  What next?  I tried:

> echo 'export PATH=Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.0/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0/bin/:$PATH' >> ~/.profile

#### ECLIPSE

Eclipse asks for Instance Name and Database name in two separate fields.  I've tried every permutation of Project ID:database name (e.g. petproject:dog).

Here is the Eclipse error report (its the same every time):

> Could not connect to Profile (name-of-the-project-in-Eclipse.GoogleCloudSQL.DevInstance).
>   Error creating SQL Model Connection connection to Profile (name-of-the-project-in-Eclipse.GoogleCloudSQL.DevInstance). (Error: Access denied for user 'my-login-id'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
>   Access denied for user 'my-login-id'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>   Error creating Google Cloud SQL Connection factory connection to Profile (pse:
>   Could not connect to Profile (name-of-the-project-in-Eclipse.GoogleCloudSQL.DevInstance). (Error: Access denied for user 'my-login-id'@'localhost' (using password: YES))

#### Other

I can get a test app to work just fine.  I have the test app running through a domain that I own.  I've created a Google Cloud SQL project and instance.  I've given permission for my app to use the instance on the Google API console.  I have local  mysql running and created the database/schema on my machine.  I can't link up my local database to the GWT because the entire Google Cloud SQL needs to function.

Thanks -- very much appreciated.